# Security when working on a users laptop with their credentials

Tags: windows, security, single-sign-on

We are implementing many services with kerberos and single sign on.  A security concern has been raised relating to how we fix issues with our users laptops.  Typically the user will leave a device with our IT service desk team - either logged in or with their password transferred.  The issue comes as we now launch a HR portal with single sign on.  We are concerned that the users personal details can be obtained.  Currently we don't have a workaround.  What do other people do with regards to security in this situation?

Comment: Don't logon as the user or work on the computer with the users credentials. Don't request or accept the users password. Logon with your administrator account. If the problem is only replicatable under the users logged in context then make sure the user is present during your triage and resolution.

Comment: Is that enough?  I feel like there should be a bullet proof mechanism - an idea i had was to use a password manager tool, and have the computer accessed via this so that the session could be recorded.  Is that too much?  Relying on people not to circumvent is always my last approach...

Comment: We can't tell you what's enough for you. Determine what your needs are and then design a solution that meets those needs. We can't answer that for you.

Answer (score 4):

Do not ask for their password, that encourages bad habits. Users should know to **never** provide personal passwords to anybody.

As an administrator, you have visibility to most of their data, do things as yourself. Becoming them invites the possibility of seeing what you should not (your HR example). And you can do things as them. A professional would have the ethics to not do anything improper, but why even allow the possibility.

If you must become them, do so with them present.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways for me as an admin to impersonate the user and gather all his data: software keyloggers, scripts, tampered files, remote spying (desktop shadowing, for example)... So this CANNOT be seen as a problem, anyway. The admin needs to be trusted.